# Is being non-Muslim-controlled sufficient for a country to be a target of lesser jihad?

Tags: jihad, non-muslim-countries, violence

Is being non-Muslim-controlled sufficient reason for a country to be the target of lesser jihad?

For example, as far as I know Cambodia hasn't attacked any Muslim countries, and currently allows Muslims to practice their religion (though it once had a brutal dictatorship that attacked many religions). Is it being non-Muslim-controlled sufficient reason for it to be a target of lesser jihad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, according to Quran (chapter 60, verse 8):
{Allah does not forbid you from those who do not fight you because of religion and do not expel you from your homes - from being righteous toward them and acting justly toward them. Indeed, Allah loves those who act justly}

ِAnd Quran chapter 2, verse 190:
{Fight in the way of Allah those who fight you but do not transgress. Indeed. Allah does not like transgressors}

Comment: "Allah does not forbid you" - "Forbid you" from what? Also, in the second quote, what does "transgress" mean?

Comment: Means does not forbid of being friends with .......... And transgress means committing aggression without a reason, i.e. without being provoked by an aggressor. And even in the latter case, the retaliation should not exceed the extent of the damage caused be the aggressor (not transgress).